# Vector field along immersion - How do you extend, locally, a vector field along an immersion?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Suppose we have an immersion $f$ between $S$ and $M$. Moreover, suppose that $X$ is a smooth vector field on $f(S)$. Prove that we can extend $X$ to a open neighborhood $V$ of $f(S)$ on $M$. Here $M$ and $S$ are a smooth manifold of dimension $k$ and $n+k$ respectively.

What I see is that you can extend this vector field in a 'parallel' way but I don't know how to formalize this idea.

Comment: Is $X$ just any vector fields? Is it continuous/differentiable (in some sense)?

Comment: Yes, of course is a smooth vector field.

Comment: How do you define a smooth vector field on $f(S)$, which is not a smooth manifold?

Comment: $f$ is smooth and $S$ is a smooth manifold. I don't know if you have Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds from Warner. There is a comment on page 39:

'It is easy to prove that a $C^{\infty}$ vector field $X$ along an immersion $\psi:M \rightarrow N$ always has a local $C^{\infty}$ extension to N.'

Comment: Think of $S = \mathbb R$, then $f(S)$ can be a dense subset in $M$ which is neither open nor closed. There is no smooth structure on $f(S)$. (I don't have the book with me)

Comment: The comment is explicitly stated like that. Possibly is wrong or he is thinking about an injective immersion, I don't know but I need this proposition to prove another result.

Comment: Ok, what I see on the book is something like:

Let $\psi:M \rightarrow N$. A smooth vector field $X$ along $\psi$ (that is, $X \in C^{\infty}(M,TN)$ and $\pi \circ X = \psi$) ...

Comment: What you ask in your question is different from what Warner claims in his comment.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Just read the definition of "local $C^\infty$ extensions" given in Warner, its just above the remark you quoted. Also, one can define what a smooth function defined on an arbitrary subset of a manifold is, so your phrase "smooth vectorfield on $f(S)$" makes sense, but Warner means a "vectorfield along $f$ " which is something different.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Do you know how to write this properly (I mean the solution)?

Comment: Maybe edit your question?